# mac RPN calculator inconsistency

Tags: macos, calculator

Using Calculator Version 4.5.3 (99.2) on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)

Putting the calculator in RPN mode

1. Empty stack and press:  8 ENTER
2. Empty stack and press:  8 ENTER ENTER 1 *

(8 can be any number)

Both 1. and 2. leaves the calculator in seemingly the same state, but it is not, which will be clear when the next number is pressed. This is very annoying for me as I often forget what I am doing mid calculation often forget what I am doing mid sentence. Is there any solution?

Comment: I don't follow. Why would you hit ENTER twice?

Comment: That's more or less the standard behavior. If enter didn't duplicate the bottom variable, you'd often need a separate action for duplicating it if you wanted to use it for another operation but also keep a copy in the stack.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Because first ENTER is to enter the number, and second ENTER is for making a duplicate.

Comment: @LauriRanta: Yes the duplicate function of ENTER is desired and expected. The problem is that you can not see if the number, you have pressed is entered or not. On "hp 49g+"(and many others) the number enter area and the stack is separated - this solution is way better.

Comment: It's doomed. Very simple thing that proves that Apple can't fix trivial errors for years.